# Force the input field for to have the first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On SO there are many solutions to have the first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase. 
But I want it to be forced instantly in the input field.

I'm new to AngularJs and where I am working, we are using Angular 1.7.x.

I have found something like this, but it doesn't work properly.

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase(0) + this.value.substring(1)"
```

Comment: Please show more information about your code

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to do this? And why doesn't your example work?

If you are happy with the first letter of each word in the input being capitialised then you can achieve it just via css by setting `text-transform: capitalize` although this will only affect how the text appears on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your attempt has the JS in a string, this should work:

```
this.value = this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to use JS for doing this.

**Just use the CSS or Bootstrap class.**

**CSS example:**

```
.capitalize {
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<span class="capitalize">{{ yourModelName }}</span>
```

***UPDATE 1:*** **Bootstrap Way:**

```
<p class="text-capitalize">CapiTaliZed text.</p>
```